# Tkinter destroy TopLevel window and create a new one in its place with one button

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Currently I am trying to destroy toplevel window (***If*** it's there, if not create it) and spawn a new one in its place.

Currently the button that creates the window, makes a small window that has a label, that just shows a command line based off user inputs on the GUI.

However, I've tried googling and tons of different ways, but I can't get it to destroy the window and create a new one.

```
def view_command():  # Views Command
    cmd_line_window = Toplevel()
    cmd_line_window.title('Command Line')
    cmd_line_window.configure(background="#434547")

    #doing stuff here#

    cmd_label = Label(cmd_line_window, text=example_cmd_output, foreground="white",
                      background="#434547")
    cmd_label.config(font=("Helvetica", 16))
    cmd_label.pack()

btn = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=view_command)
```

I've tried some `if` statements, some `try` statements, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I feel like there is a simple way to do this in one function, however I can't seem to get it.

**Edit:** Currently, each time I click the button it updates all my variables that I've chosen and displays the correct thing, it just keeps spawning more windows with the updated label.

**Edit2:** I used advice from the comments and the answer on the bottom to get the best of both worlds. This is my code, it opens a window or updates a label based on rather or not the window is already open!

```
def view_command():
    global cmd_label
    example_cmd_output = acodec_stream_choices[acodec_stream.get()] \
                     + encoder_dropdownmenu_choices[encoder.get()] + \
                     acodec_bitrate_choices[acodec_bitrate.get()] + \
                     acodec_channel_choices[acodec_channel.get()] + \
                     acodec_samplerate_choices[acodec_samplerate.get()] + \
                     acodec_gain_choices[acodec_gain.get()] + ac3_custom_cmd_input + ac3_title_input
    try:
        cmd_label.config(text=example_cmd_output)
    except (AttributeError, NameError):
        cmd_line_window = Toplevel()
        cmd_line_window.title('Command Line')
        cmd_line_window.configure(background="#434547")
        cmd_label = Label(cmd_line_window, text=example_cmd_output, foreground="white", background="#434547")
        cmd_label.config(font=("Helvetica", 16))
        cmd_label.pack()

    btn = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=view_command)
```

Comment: Call the [`.destroy()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method on the current `Toplevel` instance.

Comment: I've been trying to call .destroy() on the Toplevel instance, before it creates a new one, however, it'll just loop at not make a new window at all.

Comment: u want to destory the `Toplevel()` and create a new one? or when the button is pressed, u want to check if any toplevel exist adn then delete all the existing toplevel ? can u explain a bit more

Comment: Can you just update the label text instead of destroying and creating window?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, I have a Window, that has several drop down menus etc, once the user is done with their selection there is a button that allows them to see the command line they chose. 

When they press this button a window opens up with a label based off of what they chose. 

If they change settings and press it again I want it to delete the window that's there and open a new one.

acw1668 I suppose that would work fine, as long as it opened up the tiny window first with the label and updated the label with each press. It would need to check if the window was there, if not open it.

Comment: Jessie: You could use the `try`/`catch` technique — similar to what's in my answer below — to create the window _and_ the button if they don't already exist. Once that's done, you can then just update/replace the text in the existing button with the universal widget [`config()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. This would me more efficient and use less memory that destroying and recreating the `Toplevel` window and `Button` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can just call the universal widget [`destroy()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html) method to get rid of any current `Toplevel` that may already exist. However, since you didn't post your own code that attempted to do that (but didn't work), here's a runnable example that does:

```
import tkinter as tk


def view_command():  # Views Command
    global cmd_line_window

    try:
        cmd_line_window.destroy()
    except (AttributeError, NameError):
        pass

    cmd_line_window = tk.Toplevel()
    cmd_line_window.title('Command Line')
    cmd_line_window.configure(background="#434547")

    #doing stuff here#

    cmd_label = tk.Label(cmd_line_window, text=example_cmd_output, foreground="white",
                         background="#434547")
    cmd_label.config(font=("Helvetica", 16))
    cmd_label.pack()


example_cmd_output = 'example cmd output'
root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=view_command)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

##### Update

As @acw1668 and I mentioned in other comments, an even better way to do this would be to only create the `Toplevel` window and `Label` *once* and then afterwards just update the text of the `Label` (instead of destroying and recreating everything everytime the `Button` is clicked. Again, a `try`/`except` is used to easily implement this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def view_command():  # Views Command
    global cmd_line_window
    global cmd_label

    #doing stuff here#
    example_cmd_output = 'example cmd output'

    try:
        cmd_label.config(text=example_cmd_output)  # Update Label's text.
    except (NameError, tk.TclError):  # Label or Toplevel widget doesn't exist.
        cmd_line_window = tk.Toplevel()
        cmd_line_window.title('Command Line')
        cmd_line_window.configure(background="#434547")
        cmd_label = tk.Label(cmd_line_window, font=("Helvetica", 16),
                             foreground="white", background="#434547",
                             text=example_cmd_output)
        cmd_label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=view_command)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was putting this part of the code

   " try:
        cmd_line_window.destroy()
    except (AttributeError, NameError):
        pass"

In the wrong spot causing the error. I appreciate the detailed response and the solution. I still can't upvote yet, but I did mark it as the accepted solution!

Comment: I did end up using it that way. Works perfectly!

Thanks for the help everyone!